# Get a SqlControlSource to pass a parameter from a devexpress grid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress, sqldatasource

I am creating a SqlDataSource connected to a stored procedure that needs parameters. I have connected my SqlDataSource to a ASP.NET devexpress grid and would like to use a combo box drop down from the grid to be the parameter to the SQLDataSource Parameter source Control. I can see other controls in the list but not any from the grid.[image: Screen Shot]

How can I get a Combo Drop down to be the control for the parameter? I am using VB.Net

Answer (score 0):

Select the required ASPxComboBox control from the ControlID list and ASPxComboBox.Value property as PropertyName:

[Tutorial 5: Declarative Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581786.aspx)

Take a look at the following samples, which may be helpful:

[E2040](http://www.devexpress.com/example=E2040)

[E2041](http://www.devexpress.com/example=E2041)

Comment: Hi mikhail, I dont think that this will work for me as the combo is part of the devexpress grid not an external combo box.

Comment: Please share the ASPxGridView and SqlDataSource markup. Why don't you contact DevExpress guys?